# Thick border in xlsxwriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Is there any option to add thick border in Excel using xlsxwriter?

I'm writing a border between a range using conditional format.

Add table won't work in my case.[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is there any option to add thick border in Excel using xlsxwriter?

You can use a cell format with a border style 2 or 5 for this. See the weight column in the [Format set_border() method](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#format-set-border):

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('borders.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

format1 = workbook.add_format({'border': 1})
format2 = workbook.add_format({'border': 2})
format3 = workbook.add_format({'border': 5})

worksheet.write('B3', 'Border 1', format1)
worksheet.write('B6', 'Border 2', format2)
worksheet.write('B9', 'Border 5', format3)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

Note however, as far as I know Excel doesn't support/allow thicker borders in conditional formats. As far as I can see the only weight allowed, via the dialog, is 1, i.e., standard thickness.

Also note, there is no direct way in XlsxWriter to apply a border around a range. You will need to apply the appropriate border formats (8+ formats) to all the cells at the edges of the range. This is what Excel does, it is just hidden behind the GUI.

Comment: Is it possible to change the color of the border ? I am not seeing anything int the documentation.

Comment: Try `set_border_color()` or `border_color` as a parameter: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#format-set-border-color

Comment: Nice solution, you saved my time.